# unable to connect to Sonarqube via intellij (SonarLint)

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am trying to integrate sonarqube(version 5.1.2) with intellij(2016.2). I have added sonarLint plugin.
when I am trying to add a sonar server to the sonarLint settings it asks for username and password for sonar server and other details like url.
But it somehow is unable to connect to the sonar server and gives error :
Fail to request : https://example.com/api/system/status

[image]

Comment: probably the certificate issue.

Comment: I am able to connect to the sonar server via browser and login with my credentials. My Sonarqube version is 5.1 and it cannot be changed. Any idea what other plugin I can uise with intellij 2016.2 to integrate with sonarqube

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of SonarLint only supports SonarQube 5.6+ (5.6 is the current LTS version).

Apart of that, you might also be facing a problem with server SSL certificates. SonarLint will try to validate the server's SSL certificate using the JVM's truststore. So if your SonarQube server uses an SSL certificate, you might need to install the CA certificate in the trustore of the JVM used by IntelliJ.

Due to a limitation in SonarLint, certificates configured within IntelliJ aren't supported by SonarLint: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-75

Answer (score 2):

I ran into something similar myself using SonarLint 3.1 and SonarQube 6.7.

In IntelliJ I kept running into this error message

```
Failed to connect to the server. Please check the configuration.
Error: Fail to request https://<SONARQUBE>/api/system/status
```

However I could access that URL through my browser without any issues.

When you WireShark the requests coming from the browser and the IDE you can see that the cypher suite is quite different and that the IDE plugin gets a TLS handshake failure.

That lead me to discover that Java still ships with limited strength cryptographic functions. That’s either because of US export policy or because  nobody has gotten around to fixing it. The internet isn’t quite sure.

Either way, you can download the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Once I installed those onto the IntelliJ JVM, I no longer got the underlying TLS handshake failure when trying to connect to SonarQube and the connection works.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late response, but you can try to follow this instruction.

You can find it here. Download the Zip and follow the instructions in the pop-up after you click download.
[Versions: SonarLint - IntelliJ IDEs Plugin | Marketplace (jetbrains.com)](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint/versions)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error. After many tries, it turned out that I had to enter my *login* (it's a domain account) in the **upper-case**. Looks like *login* is case-sensitive.
It's my work account and I was using it always in lower-case, so it's quite surprising, but worked nonetheless.